# Selenium Compound Class Name [unable to insert a value]

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently having a hard time inserting a value into a field which is within a Frame, I have tried removing the spaces in the class name but it didn't work

**class=**"ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty input-sm form-control nc-pristine ng-valid-required ng-touched"

```html
<textarea ng-if="$ctrl.fieldType.isTextarea($ctrl.field.fieldType, $ctrl.field.isHtmlFormatted)" ng-model="$ctrl.field.value" ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()" ng-required="$ctrl.field.isRequired" ng-class="{
    'input-sm': true,
    'form-control': true,
    'nc-pristine': $ctrl.getPristine(),
    'nc-not-pristine': $ctrl.getNotPristine()
   }" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty input-sm form-control nc-pristine ng-valid-required ng-touched"></textarea>
```

I have tried in Chrome Developer tool and it worked with this javascript code

**Chrome Console Developper Javascript**

```html
document.getElementsByClassName('ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty input-sm form-control nc-pristine ng-valid-required ng-touched')[0].value='Hello World';
```

In Selenium I tried with these 2 ways none of them work:

**Using Javascript**

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByClassName('ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty input-sm form-control nc-pristine ng-valid-required ng-touched')[0].value='Hello World';");
```

**Error Message:**

```
 System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=unknown error: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
   at ConsoleApp5.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

**Using cssSelector, removing the spacing in the Class Name and replacing it with dots**

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-scope.ng-empty.input-sm.form-control.nc-pristine.ng-valid-required.ng-touched")).SendKeys("Hello World");
```

**Error Message**

```
  OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-scope.ng-empty.input-sm.form-control.nc-pristine.ng-valid-required.ng-touched"}
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByCssSelector(String cssSelector)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<CssSelector>b__0(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
```

Comment: that textarea element has multiple classes associated with it.  e.g. ng-pristine, ng-valid, etc.  try your css selector, but replace those "."s with a space.  That said, you may have multiple text areas with the same classes.  Look at the parent or grandparent to see if there's a better path to find that textarea.  If you provide more of the HTML we could help you find that.

Comment: thank you for your answer, the HTML has thousands of lines, I don't know how to put that here with the question text length limitation

Comment: Here is the error message I get when I remove the spacing:   OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty input-sm form-control nc-pristine ng-valid-required ng-touched"}

Comment: You no need to put the whole HTML at here, you can stat with the parent node near by the  textarea which can  limit the find scope within the parent node,  if the near parent node can not make the find result unique, you need include more parent node  which more far  away from textarea.

Comment: You don't need to include all of the html for the page. If you can provide a link to the actual page, that would be ideal.  Otherwise you can edit your question to include, perhaps up to the previous 5 levels above your textarea, and remove extraneous elements.

Comment: Added more HTML Code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the html provided try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div > div > nc-editable-field > textarea"));
```

Also, you stated that the element is in Frame, are you sure that you are switching to that frame correctly?

Comment: Yes, this worked, can you explain how you were able to have that Css selector, here it the full copy from google chrome: #ncScreenSectionFormBuilder > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > div > div > nc-screen-section-form-builder > div.container-fluid > div > div > form > div:nth-child(4) > nc-form-group-template:nth-child(1) > div > nc-editable-field-template > div > div > nc-editable-field > textarea

Comment: The By.cssSelector will allow you to use any part of the selector path, thus you could use the full path, but sometimes that is way to long.  using only parts of the selector will work about 90% of the time, however you can run into cases where you will have duplicate selector paths.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, and this is working for every field, thanks a lot

Comment: A lesson learnt, to see things in simpler ways. Wasted almost 2 hours with JavaScript. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is more HTML Code below

```html
<div class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="field in $ctrl.getFields() as fields" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">
       <!-- ngRepeat: i in [$index, $index + 1] --><!-- ngIf: fields[i] --><nc-form-group-template ng-repeat="i in [$index, $index + 1]" ng-if="fields[i]" section-id="a1gg0000002ARlMAAW" guid="a1gg0000002ARlMAAW338C1B4330ED4993A7B3178099C70517" field="fields[i]" context-id="a38g0000001juVQAAY" ,="" enable-field-access="$ctrl.enableFieldAccess" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
   <nc-field-label-template section-id="a1gg0000002ARlMAAW" field="$ctrl.field" inline-help-text="" label="Other Loan Purpose" is-required="$ctrl.field.isRequired" enable-field-access="$ctrl.enableFieldAccess" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="row content-label">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <span ng-show="$ctrl.inlineHelpText" popover="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-content="" class="fa fa-info-circle slds-show--inline ng-hide" data-original-title="" title="">
    </span>
    <label ng-bind="$ctrl.label" class="form-control-static input-sm slds-show--inline ng-binding" ng-class="{'is-required': $ctrl.isRequired, 'pull-left': $ctrl.enableFieldAccess}">Other Loan Purpose</label>
    <span class="slds-p-left--medium">
     <!-- ngIf: !$ctrl.field.isVisible && $ctrl.enableFieldAccess -->
     <span class="slds-assistive-text">This field will be hidden from the user.</span>
    </span>
    <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.enableFieldAccess -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </nc-field-label-template>
   <!-- ngIf: !$ctrl.isReadOnly() --><nc-editable-field-template ng-if="!$ctrl.isReadOnly()" section-id="a1gg0000002ARlMAAW" guid="a1gg0000002ARlMAAW338C1B4330ED4993A7B3178099C70517" field="$ctrl.field" context-id="a38g0000001juVQAAY" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 content-body">
    <nc-editable-field section-id="a1gg0000002ARlMAAW" guid="a1gg0000002ARlMAAW338C1B4330ED4993A7B3178099C70517" field="$ctrl.field" context-id="a38g0000001juVQAAY" class="ng-isolate-scope">
 
  <!-- ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isTextarea($ctrl.field.fieldType, $ctrl.field.isHtmlFormatted) --><textarea ng-if="$ctrl.fieldType.isTextarea($ctrl.field.fieldType, $ctrl.field.isHtmlFormatted)" ng-model="$ctrl.field.value" ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()" ng-required="$ctrl.field.isRequired" ng-class="{
    'input-sm': true,
    'form-control': true,
    'nc-pristine': $ctrl.getPristine(),
    'nc-not-pristine': $ctrl.getNotPristine()
   }" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty input-sm form-control nc-pristine ng-valid-required ng-touched"></textarea><!-- end ngIf: $ctrl.fieldType.isTextarea($ctrl.field.fieldType, $ctrl.field.isHtmlFormatted) -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code block :

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByClassName('ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty input-sm form-control nc-pristine ng-valid-required ng-touched')[0].click()");
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByClassName('ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty input-sm form-control nc-pristine ng-valid-required ng-touched')[0].value='Hello World'");
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the following error message  System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=unknown error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
  Source=WebDriver